# Polymer in Chrome for iOS - it is not working, right?

Tags: ios, google-chrome, polymer, polyfills

I was all excited over Polymer and starting developing a web app. I soon found out that Firefox fails loading the site correctly, see this SO post for details:

[Polymer: Layout screwed up in Firefox, fine in Chrome](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27480345/polymer-layout-screwed-up-in-firefox-fine-in-chrome)

Then, I downloaded the latest version of Chrome on an iPhone 4 (iOS7) and the same thing for iPhone 6 (iOS8) and tried the website. I see the same errors as I see on Firefox (please see the link above).

In other words - going to my Polymer based website using Chrome for iOS fails just as bad as Firefox fails.

- So, I'd just like to confirm that this is the case: Polymer does not work on iOS (no support in Safari, no support in Chrome for iOS). Correct?

As I also noted in my other SO question linked above, I was expecting it to work in all browser due to "polyfill", but that doesn't seem to help.

Am I missing something?

Note: Using Chrome for Android works fine, no errors there.

Comment: Should work, the polyfill works quite nicely. Check the polyfill documentation, there is full support for Firefox (in principle), so try to get it working in Firefox first (using console debugging) and then check again :)

Comment: Thanks, I have been trying but I can figure it out to be honest. The site is very very simple, even in its most basic form, the Polyfill (ShadowDOM) isnt working. I have updated the SO question with a test I made: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27480345/polymer-layout-screwed-up-in-firefox-fine-in-chrome

Comment: I cannot see what's wrong either. I suggest you remove all styling and add rule by rule to see where it breaks.

Comment: I uploaded the stuff to an URL: http://misc.snapcode.se/polymer/  Can you see if it is weird in Firefox on your end?

Comment: If you remove the padding and margin on "div" it should work. It looks fine on my Firefox. Did you clear your cache and do you have a recent version?

Comment: Yes, I commented that in my post linked above. Removing DIV css, it looks better. However, why cant I use it there? It shouldnt affect the rest, as it does not in Chrome. Are you saying it looks OK in your Firefox? Cause I have the latest version, and have tried on several other browsers (Safari, FF oh other computers), and its all the same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I mentioned in the other thread, it's impossible to polyfill CSS scoping. Chrome on iOS is not actually Chrome, it's built using the iOS WebView (an old one at that), meaning there's no native Shadow DOM and no CSS scoping. The Shadow DOM polyfill does properly wrap DOM API methods like querySelector and getElementById, so you do get **limited** encapsulation, in that respect. But for CSS, the only thing the polyfill can do is rename your selectors, so :host .blah gets renamed to x-foo .blah and appended to a style tag in the head. It means you need to still write defensive CSS (as you do today) and avoid very loose selectors because they will be applied.

Answer (score 0):

I experienced something very weird today and maybe it might help you.

My firefox was rendering as if  polyfills didn't existed.
So i went back to false on `about:config`  dom.webcomponents.enabled and it came back to life.

Why? no clue.
It worked, so, if you have `dom.webcomponents.enabled` `true` on firefox `about:config` might as well give it a try. IMHO looks like a polyfill bug on capable (yet buggy and poorly supported) web components browsers. worth a try.

Comment: Thanks for that. If I go to about:config and scroll down to dom.webcomponents.enabled, it is set to false. However, if I switch it to true, and then reload the page, its even worse than before, now I only see the text "LEO" and a white small box. So it works better with that set to "false"...

Comment: I still suspect that its the ShadowDOM that fails somehow. Please see my other SO question if you are interested in the details.

Comment: Can I ask if you have a Polymer website up and running somehwere, that I can test?
There must be something obvious Im missing...

Comment: The only one i have is from a company i'm working 4h/day and it is password protected. Sorry. have you tried prototyping it on polymer designer tool? are you on polymer 0.5.2? and least but not last (this gave me issues too: you HAVE to Polymer("element-name",{etc}); Polymer({etc}); wont do for firefox and others.

Comment: Yeah, it looks ok on that part. This is a CSS thing it seems, not that the elements dont render at all.

Comment: kinda solved my problem by avoiding binding in style inside templates, added them inline and forcem polyfill to pickup using "_" like _style="{{myVar}}". also strict heights and widths.

Comment: Thanks for that update Caio, but I dont see it is a tenable solution. Those hacks usually make the whole thing unstable in the end... I'd like to know if there is a real answer - Polyfill does not handle well in Firefox, so CSS cannot be used?

Comment: you can use styles but the binding inside them with polymer has a known bug on firefox. I can't recall if it's firefox side or polymer side so that was the workaround. If it's polymer side it'll soon be corrected, the issue has a lot of attention.